# Detecting loops using patterns in the Program Counter (Instruction Pointer) values

Tags: algorithm, parsing, reverse-engineering

I have the sequence of values a Program Counter takes while executing a particular code. Using this, I'd like to do some static analysis of the original code that produced this executable (to be clear: the original code is NOT available) - particularly, how many loops are there, and how they are nested. To give an example,

```
A: for()
B:     if () 
C:         ...
D:     else
E:         ...
F:     for () {
G:         ...
H:         ...
I:     }
```

In this case, the program counter sequence might be: A B C D F {G H I G H I G H I} A B D E F {G H I G H I} A B D E F {G H I G H I G H I G H I}

From the above sequence, how can I get an idea that there are two loops, and one is nested within the other? Just pointers toward the appropriate parsing techniques to use would be helpful too.

Some simplifying assumptions such as no goto in the original code and no compiler-optimized loop unrolling can be made.

Comment: Why don't you just analyze the original code and detect the loops it contains (using standard control flow analysis algorithms)?  What do the PC values provide (except verification that particular points are actually code)? [That might be useful in obfuscated code that has deliberate non-executed jumps to nonsense locations]

Comment: ... My reaction comes from the fact that you claim to have the source code, and that's an extremely high quality source of information, and yet you seem to be looking elsewhere for that same information.

Comment: @IraBaxter I've edited the question to clarify that the original source code is not available. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Aha.  OK. you got the PC data from executing something; why don't you analyze the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a graph out of program counter sequence, where each program counter is a vertex and each pair of consecutive program counters in the sequence is a directed edge. (If you have several edges from one vertex to another, keep only one of them).
2. Starting from the vertex, produced by the first program counter in the sequence, perform depth-first search to find cycles. After each cycle is found, move last edge of this cycle to a separate list.
3. After all cycles are found and moved out of the graph, you have a DAG (directed acyclic graph). Perform topological sorting on this DAG to restore correct sequence of statements in the program, exactly as in source code, except if/else blocks (you cannot determine from the program counter sequence which one is 'if', and which one is 'else'). To get a proper result, in cases when topological sorting does not prescribe any particular order, depth-first search ordering should be used. To properly place while/for loop bodies, some additional information from step 2 may be used: loop detection algorithm may mark second node of each loop.
4. To analyze if/else blocks, create a separate list of splits/merges in the graph.
5. Combine list of loops (extracted on step 2) and list of if/else (extracted on step 4) into a single list of intervals. Use relationship of these intervals (which one is nested within the other) to construct a tree for all for/if/else statements.
6. In some cases, 'if' block at the end of 'while' loop `while{...if{}}` may be detected incorrectly, as while{loop{}...}, with the same starting address of 'while' and 'loop'. Since starting address of 'while' cannot coincide with starting address of any nested loop, this may be easily post-processed back to `while{...if{}}`. (Nested 'do-while' loops may have the same starting address, but they do not have any problems with nested 'if').

---

This approach works only in simplest case, when there are no 'goto', 'break', or any other jumps out of cycles and when 'for' loops check only a single condition.